# "WhosThere" app is not installing in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04

I'm getting this error

"E: Package 'whosthere' has no installation candidate"
"E: Unable to locate package telepathy-whosthere"

any ideas how to fix this please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the file with your favorite text editor (with root) :

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/m-gehre-ppa-raring.list
```

Change "raring" to "quantal" as following :

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/m-gehre/ppa/ubuntu quantal main
```

Then install whosthere

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install whosthere
```

**Please note that the package development is discontinued.**

Comment: Although this is a bit late but it's better late than never. Thank you!

Comment: will this have any effects later on when I try to install other apps ? because I use my laptop for work so I don't want to ruin other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's not in your repositories.
Try to refresh (`apt-get update`), then, if still no success, add a new repo, which *does* contain this package.

Comment: I have added the it to the repos before, and when I run the apt-get update command it's giving me this which I think has nothing to do with this particular app ..
"W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/deluge-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/deluge-team/ppa/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
"

Comment: Didn't you just forget to update?

Comment: I actually didn't.

Comment: So, that's it - `404 Not Found`, try to paste the url into browser. It's invalid. Remove the repo and find a working one.

Comment: I'm a bit of a noob, how can I remove this repo ?

Comment: Find a program called "software and updates" (don't remeber the exact name). Besides other things, it provides a tool to manage repositories.

Comment: @Kmelkon http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa